# Symfony - Array of object, object empty

Tags: api, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have made an api for an android application and I want to serialize my Json response thanks to JMS Serializer.

I have a entity call "**activity**" linked by a ManyToOne relation with an other entity "**specificity**".

But when I call my api request /activities to return a list of all the activities in my database, I see my activity information but not the data for the object specificity.

Can you help me? I hope my screenshot will give you more details.

Have a nice day.

[Screenshot about entity Specificity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uuvj.png)

[Screenshot about entity Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcwAC.png)

[Activity Serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xkvu.png)

[Activity Controller - Method to get all the activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ1O9.png)

[Json response with empty specificity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2vq3.png)

Comment: Post code in the post itself, Don't attach images of code. Images are for referencing the output if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a 'Specificity' serialization file like the Activity with the same used group 'activity' to specify what exactly are the properties to be returned by the serializer when serializing your specificity object.